# How to rotating a DXF world map along the longitude using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I don't know much of GIS in general, but I tried to find an answer for that for a long time.

I have a vector world map in SVG (CRS Equal Earth) that I converted to DXF in Inkscape. I want to rotate it in along the longitude by 10°, so that I get all of Asia contiguous on the right.

I can easily do that with a raster image using **Warp (reproject)**, but I can't find a way to the same using vector data. I tried the **Reproject Layer** tool but it doesn't seem to work (even changing to completely different CRS the map shows no change) and I don't know what else I can do.

**EDIT:** I think I have new information that might help. My vector layer has a very small extend, only a couple of degrees (instead of the -180 to 180 of a regular projection). How can I increase the extend of a vector layer to be the same as the extend of a raster layer?

After using **Affine transform** I could make the layer somewhat close to the correct size, but it still very far off, there is probably a better way:
[image]

Now I could at least change the projection and it seemed like it is working as it should, appart from a few broken lines:
[image]

**EDIT2:** I just noticed that when I import my DXF the entities imported are LineStrings, and I couldn't find a way to Toggle Editing for manual georeferencing. Not sure what I can do about this.

What is the proper way to align an unreferenced vector layer to a raster image?

Comment: How is your map georeferenced?

Comment: The vector layer doesn't have any geoinformation, which is probably what is causing issue, and I don't know how to add such information besides guessing with Affine Transform. I edited my question with more information.

Comment: IF you need to ask a question on georeferencing, you should ask a new question - and keep this question on the rotation (or close this if rotation is not really the question?)

Comment: Thanks, just did that I'm going to ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Please try in QGIS, on the General tab of the Layer Properties, there is an Update Extents button

[image]

Comment: My window is a bit different but equal to the documentation (https://docs.qgis.org/3.34/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#source-properties), however the Update extents buttons doesn't seem to do anything. It is clickable but I couldn't see a change even after I tried to enlarge the vector layer with Affine Transformations

Answer (score 0):

The issue here was that I'm missing georeferencing information, the Reproject Layer tool works fine as expected.